# Git cli not terminating on pull --rebase

Tags: git, sh

I am running Git v2.15.1.2 on a 64-bit machine. Whenever I try executing `$ git pull -r` to pull the latest update of my GitHub repo, this will happen:

1) The pull is successful, but it never returns to  the line where I can type.
2) No matter how long I wait, it just bails out into a `sh.exe.stackdump` file.

I tried reinstalling numerous times Git without any difference, and it works perfectly fine on my other computers. Do you guys know any way to fix this?

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit git installation?

Comment: Do you have ConEmu installed? A console emulator that can also be embedded into other such programs, such as Cmder.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlse it works now, thanks, but I'd still be interested to know how to fix it in Git itself.

Comment: Since you haven't told us anything we could use to help you that's going to be quite difficult.

Comment: I dunno what I can tell more about, @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, since I have no clue why it only happens on _this_ particular computer

Answer (score 0):

This was seen in [git-for-windows/git issue 1630](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1630) for Git for Windows 2.13 to 2.17.

> We are constantly haunted by anti-malware triggering by mistake on our fork of the Cygwin runtime, which is needed to execute Unix shell scripts (and git stash is implemented as such).

[Git 2.19.0-rc0](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/v2.19.0-rc0.windows.1) is supposed to be more robust against that type of error.

Since this was for `git stash`, check if your local config has a `pull.rebase=true` and `rebase.autostash=true`.

Comment: See https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.19.1.windows.1 and https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/1852